# About spark and hbase

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hbase

This is the first time I ask question, if there's any place I should improve please tell me, thanks.

Here is my system version :

- `jdk1.8.0_65`
- `hadoop-2.6.1`
- `hbase-1.0.2`
- `scala-2.11.7`
- `spark-1.5.1`
- `zookeeper-3.4.6`

Then there is my question:

1. I'm gonna built a system that can store data from sensors
   I need to store data in it and to analysis the data near
   real-time, so I use spark to make my analysis run faster,
   but I'm wondering "Do I Really Need Hbase Database" ?
2. There is some problem when I run Spark:

First I run: `hadoop:start-all.sh` and `Spark:start-all.sh`, then I 
run `Spark:spark-shell`

This is what I got:

```
15 / 12 / 01 22: 16: 47 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native - hadoop library
for your platform...using builtin - java classes where applicable Welcome to Using Scala version 2.10 .4(Java HotSpot(TM) 64 - Bit Server VM, Java 1.8 .0 _65)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type: help
for more information.
15 / 12 / 01 22: 16: 56 WARN MetricsSystem: Using
default name DAGScheduler
for source because spark.app.id is not set.Spark context available as sc.
15 / 12 / 01 22: 16: 59 WARN Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in CLASSPATH(or one of dependencies)
15 / 12 / 01 22: 16: 59 WARN Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in CLASSPATH(or one of dependencies)
15 / 12 / 01 22: 17: 07 WARN ObjectStore: Version information not found in metastore.hive.metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so recording the schema version 1.2 .0
15 / 12 / 01 22: 17: 07 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database
default, returning NoSuchObjectException
15 / 12 / 01 22: 17: 10 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native - hadoop library
for your platform...using builtin - java classes where applicable
15 / 12 / 01 22: 17: 11 WARN Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in CLASSPATH(or one of dependencies)
15 / 12 / 01 22: 17: 11 WARN Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in CLASSPATH(or one of dependencies)
SQL context available as sqlContext.
scala >
```

There are so many warning, am I doing the right thing? Like where can 
I set spark.app.id or even do I need spark.app.id? And what is "Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException" ?

Thank's for helping me.

Comment: First you should question if you really need Spark (and all Hadoop infrastructure) for this task. Maybe a simple java app that uses kafka would be enough.

Comment: Yes, I really need spark and hadoop infrastructure, cause I have about 20 or more than twenty sensors. Each of them will pass data to my database 10 times per second all day long, so I will need this system. In future I can extend my storage. Thanks, kostya.